# SVN projects folder structure

Tags: svn

I am new to svn. I have installed SVN on Linux CentOS 6.3 machine. I have created few projects under SVN and the location is `/var/www/svn/<MyRepos>` ..

Now that we have to create few repos under one folder, so it should look like:

```
/var/www/svn/Common/ProjA/[trunk,branch,tags]
/var/www/svn/Common/ProjB/[trunk,branch,tags]
/var/www/svn/release/ProjA/[trunk,branch,tags]
/var/www/svn/release/ProjB/[trunk,branch,tags]
```

I created `/common` directory thru Linux `mkdir` and created `/ProjA` thru `svnadmin create`, which was successful, but when tried to access from browser, it was not able to connect. Is this is the correct way to do it? please advice.

Note: The files will be imported from cvs thru cvs2svn tool as we are doing the migration from CVS to SVN.

Comment: cvs2svn is completely irrelevant to the question. Read doc: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html

Comment: @bahrep, yes i knew cvs2svn is irrelevant here, but i wanted to make my point that the code is coming from CVS, so it gives the brach, trunk structures. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I have found the solution, I just had to create new location tag in the `subversion.conf` so as to create the above said structure.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot manipulate a directory stucture in a Subversion repository using the standard shell commands `mkdir`, `cp`, `mkdir`, `mv`, etc. You must use a Subversion client and point it at the repository URL. The directory/file structure is not visible via the host filesystem - it can only be viewed and manipulated via the Subversion libraries.

Before you go *any* further, you must [read the fine manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) and gain an understanding of the basics of how the repository works and how to interact with it. You cannot just install it, throw a few shell commands around, and hope for the best.

Comment: I knew i cant just install and give few shell commands on it, but i mentioned what i tried, coz for creating the /svn parent folder i indeed created thru linux command. Also the svn mkdir wont work here, hence i mentioned that. Also I am in a position to start working with SVN by learning it along.